# XSLT use apply template to check if node exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to check if a node exists then if it does perform a calculation and store the value

since i am trying to list the opening hours

```
<xsl:variable name="Monday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OpeningHours/Monday"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="OpeningHours/node()">
    <xsl:if test="current()">
        <xsl:value-of select="Open + Close"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

although it seems I am doing something wrong somewhere

my xml is

```
<OpeningHours>
    <Monday>
        <Open>8.5</Open>
        <Close>20</Close>
    </Monday>
    <Tuesday>
        <Open>8.5</Open>
        <Close>20</Close>
    </Tuesday>
    <Wednesday>
        <Open>8.5</Open>
        <Close>20</Close>
    </Wednesday>
    <Friday>
        <Open>8.5</Open>
        <Close>22</Close>
    </Friday>
    <Saturday>
        <Open>7</Open>
        <Close>14</Close>
    </Saturday>
</OpeningHours>
```

Comment: What does your XML look like? What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: Your select='..' already selects the "existing" nodes. The 'xsl:if' seems redundant.

Comment: @MarvinSmit so you mean that it checks if it exists?

Comment: Yes. The "select=...." will select the elements it can find according to the XPath pattern and then execute the "template match=..." for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<xsd:apply-template select='{the XPath}'` will select only those elements that comply to the relative XPath of the select in its current context. After building this list internally it will "apply-templates".

In your example

```
<xsl:variable name="Monday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OpeningHours/Monday"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Will select all elements called "Monday" that have a parent "OpeningHours" and then apply the rules again. Your next "most specific match" would be the

```
<xsl:template match="OpeningHours/node()">
```

(Although its more common to write it as `<xsl:template match="OpeningHours/*">`

So, for each selected element (from the apply-templates) the template-match is called. No need to test in there if you 'have a node'.

ps; i would try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="Monday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OpeningHours/Monday"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="OpeningHours/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="Open"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Close"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you do wish to test for the existence of a node, its common to use the 'predicate' axis of an XPath. eg;

```
<apply-templates select="Monday[parent::OpeningHours]" />
```

This example XPath says; select all child elements named "Monday", but only if they have a parent element called 'OpeningHours'

Hope this helps,